# Cocos2D for iPhone: Y touch point not coherent  

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, touch, appdelegate

I am developing a vertical scrolling game and I can't get a couple of things. I manage to get the sprites moving properly I guess. For example I get some enemy to spawn at the centre of top corner of the screen (x:160 and y:480) and get them to come down by decreasing y by 1 at each update.

The odd thing is that when I detect touches in an InputLayer that I added as child to the GameScene I get right the information about the x location of the touch but the y is upside down. In other words, if I touch the spawning point (x:160 and y:480) I get the values x:160 and y:0 and if I touch the bottom part of the screen (y:0) I get y=480.

**Why is that? Shouldn't the sprite follow the same y reference?**
I guess it might have to do with the initialization of the App in AppDelegate and hence I paste my code here:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Create the main window
    window_ = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


    // Create an CCGLView with a RGB565 color buffer, and a depth buffer of 0-bits
    CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   //kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:0    //GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];

    [glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
    director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    director_.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;


    // Display FSP and SPF
    [director_ setDisplayStats:YES];

    // set FPS at 60
    [director_ setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];

    // attach the openglView to the director
    [director_ setView:glView];

    // for rotation and other messages
    [director_ setDelegate:self];

    // 2D projection
    [director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];
    //  [director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection3D];

    // Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
    if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
        CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

    // Create a Navigation Controller with the Director
    navController_ = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:director_];
    navController_.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    // set the Navigation Controller as the root view controller
    //  [window_ setRootViewController:rootViewController_];
    [window_ addSubview:navController_.view];

    // make main window visible
    [window_ makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
    // It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
    // You can change anytime.
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

    // If the 1st suffix is not found and if fallback is enabled then fallback suffixes are going to searched. If none is found, it will try with the name without suffix.
    // On iPad HD  : "-ipadhd", "-ipad",  "-hd"
    // On iPad     : "-ipad", "-hd"
    // On iPhone HD: "-hd"
    CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
    [sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:NO];             // Default: NO. No fallback suffixes are going to be used
    [sharedFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];      // Default on iPhone RetinaDisplay is "-hd"
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];                   // Default on iPad is "ipad"
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];    // Default on iPad RetinaDisplay is "-ipadhd"

    // Assume that PVR images have premultiplied alpha
    [CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];

    //Initializes static classes to create shared instance
    PlayerData *playerData = [PlayerData playerData];
    MusicLayer *musicLayer = [MusicLayer music];

    // and add the scene to the stack. The director will run it when it automatically when the view is displayed.
    [director_ pushScene: [MainMenuScene scene]]; 

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reverse the touch as well as they are a UIKit objects (UITouch*). There is a method for this

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
```